# CMake: How to specify the target on which "install" depends?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, installation

As far as I have realized, the "INSTALL" command by default depends on all available targets. How can I configure the cmake file so that "install" depends only on a specific target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INSTALL` target created by CMake depends on the `ALL_BUILD` target, which, as its name suggests, in turn depends on every other (non-custom) target in the project. There is no way to remove this dependency.

You can however exclude targets from `ALL_BUILD` by using the [`EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL.html#prop_tgt:EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL) target property:

```
add_executable(foo EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ${FOO_SOURCES})
```

Be aware though that:

> Installing a target with the EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL target property set to
>   TRUE has undefined behavior.

[Quoted from the INSTALL manpage](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html).